# Applying grepl to check for match of data table column values with list elements, and adding resulting column

Tags: r, sapply, grepl

I have two issues here. The first is that I'm not getting the expected output from the `grepl` function, and the second is that I'm unable to correctly apply a loop to add a new column based on the result of the function call.

```
myList <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6)

myList
$a
[1] 1 2 3
$b
[1] 4 5 6

myData <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)   
myData$Z = NA
myData <- as.data.table(myData) # seems necessary for grepl to work properly?

myData

    X   Y  Z
1:  9 yes NA
2:  1  no NA
3:  4 yes NA
4:  6 yes NA
5:  7  no NA
6:  2  no NA
7:  5  no NA
8:  8  no NA
9: 10  no NA
10: 3  no NA

sapply(myData[,X], function(x) grepl(x,myList))

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The output is checking whether the value in myData$X is contained within myList. My understanding is that the first row of the output is matching with myList$a, and the second row is myList$b. However, the first row of the output has correctly stated TRUE for the second and last rows of myData$X, i.e. where X == 1 and 3, respectively. However, it returns FALSE for row six, where X == 2. I would think that should return TRUE, as 2 is contained within myList$a.

Similarly, the second row of the output gives TRUE for myData$X rows three and four, where myData$x == 4 and 6, respectively. However, it does not return TRUE for row 7, where myData$X == 5. (myList$b contains 4, 5 and 6.)

~~~

My second issue is how to apply a loop to overwrite myData$Z with the title of the list element, if `grepl` returns TRUE for that particular row. Desired output:

```
    X   Y  Z
1:  9 yes NA
2:  1  no a
3:  4 yes b
4:  6 yes b
5:  7  no NA
6:  2  no a
7:  5  no b
8:  8  no NA
9: 10  no NA
10: 3  no a
```

I'd thought something like the following might work, but it returns six warning messages and doesn't produce the desired output:

```
for (i in myList) {
myData$Z[sapply(myData[,X], function(x) (grepl(x,myList)))] <- i
}
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `melt` the list and `merge` it with the data frame:

```
merge(myData, reshape2::melt(myList), by.x = "X", by.y = "value", all.x = TRUE)

#      X   L1
#  1   1 <NA>
#  2   2    a
#  3   3    a
#  4   4    a
#  5   5 <NA>
#  6   6 <NA>
#  7   7 <NA>
#  8   8    b
#  9   9    b
# 10  10    b
```

---

Data:

```
myData <- data.frame(X = 1:10)
myList <- list(a = 2:4, b = 8:10)
```

Comment: Slick. I suspected there was a solution along these lines, I'm just way too inexperienced with this kind of data processing.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `as.data.table()`, you just forgot to quote the column name. Unless you want more advanced partial matching there is no need for `grep()`.

With character strings and multiple matches

```
myList2 <- list(pet = c("cat", "dog", "horse", "bunny"), 
               food = c("pig", "chicken", "cow", "bunny"))

set.seed(1)
myData2 <- data.frame(
    X = sample(unique(unlist(myList2))),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 7, replace = TRUE)
)   

exist2 <- sapply(myList2, function(x) myData2[,"X"] %in% x)

Z <- apply(exist2, 1, function(x) names(which(x)))
myData2$Z <- sapply(Z, function(x) 
  ifelse(length(x) == 0, NA, paste(x, collapse="+")))

myData2
#         X   Y        Z
# 1     dog  no      pet
# 2   horse  no      pet
# 3 chicken yes     food
# 4   bunny yes pet+food
# 5     cat yes      pet
# 6     cow  no     food
# 7     pig yes     food
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks great. Is it possible to modify that to work with character strings instead of integers?

Comment: No modification needed. I didn't think too hard on that integer/character remark. If you want to do partial matching you'll have to do some modifications.